# The posix_memalign() function in c++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-alignment

I have read documentations about `posix_memalign()`. I still not sure how to deal with this `The value of alignment shall be a power of two multiple of sizeof(void *).`
Also, I need some error messages to check that my alignment is successful.

I need to allocate memories aligned with 64bytes for the following arrays along with error messages for check up.

```
int array_dataset [5430][20];
int X_train [4344][20];
int Y_train[4344];
int data_point [20];
int Y-test [1068];
int X_test [1068][20];
```

Comment: Have you considered [`alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas)?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux No, I have to use `posix_memalign`

Answer (score 0):

`posix_memalign` allocates aligned heap memory (similar to malloc), so cannot be used with static or auto arrays like you show.  Instead, your variables need to be pointers that you use to access the memory

```
int *Y_train = 0;
if (posix_memalign(&Y_train, 64, 4344*sizeof(*Y_train)) {
    ... there was an error
```

Note that for your odd-sized 2D arrays that may be a problem.  You can declare

```
int (*array_dataset)[20] = 0;
if (posix_memalign(&array_dataset, 64, 5340*sizeof(*array_dataset)) {
```

but doing so will only align the first subarray -- `array[0]` will be aligned on a 64-byte boundary.  But because sizeof(int[20]) is not a multiple of 64 (it is probably 80, but might be 40 or 160 on some machines), `array[1]` will not be aligned.  You might want to use `int (*array_dataset)[32];` instead to avoid this.  Or swap the indexes and use `int (*array_dataset)[5440]` -- it all depends on what you are trying to do and why you want aligned memory in the first place.